# Qwik SSG not being able to generate static pages that requires API calls

Tags: vercel, static-site-generation, qwik

I'm trying to learn the Qwik framework and I'm trying to understand how to dynamically build static pages that requires API calls to populate the content

I have a route that's `festival/[slug]/index.tsx`. Before I had the `routeLoader$` functionality that fetched content from an API server-side.

Right now I'm trying to convert this functionality into statically-generated pages.

I've followed the instruction of the docs (https://qwik.dev/docs/guides/static-site-generation/):

1. I've ran the `npm run qwik add static` command
2. To build the static pages I use `npm run build.server`
3. I've added the `onStaticGenerate` method inside the `index.tsx` like this

```
export const onStaticGenerate: StaticGenerateHandler = async () => {
  const { allFestivals } = await performRequest<IGetAllFestivalSlugs>({
    query: GET_ALL_FESTIVAL_SLUGS,
  });

  return {
    params: allFestivals.map(({ slug }) => {
      return { slug };
    }),
  };
};
```

So now I get all slugs dynamically from the APIs correctly, and I can generate the page statically.

The problem is that I don't know how to fetch datas for all the pages dynamically.

I know I shouldn't use `routeLoader$` since it's a server-side function.

Also I don't know how to populate the DocumentHead since before I used the `resolveValue` with the `routeLoader$` in order to get the content.

Here's what my `index.tsx` looks like:

```
import { component$ } from "@builder.io/qwik";
import type {
  RequestEventLoader,
  StaticGenerateHandler,
} from "@builder.io/qwik-city";
import { routeLoader$ } from "@builder.io/qwik-city";

import { type DocumentHead } from "@builder.io/qwik-city";
import {
  GET_ALL_FESTIVAL_SLUGS,
  GET_SINGLE_FESTIVAL,
} from "~/lib/constants/api/queries";
import { performRequest } from "~/lib/datocms";
import type {
  IGetAllFestivalSlugs,
  IGetSingleFestival,
} from "~/lib/models/cms";

export const useGetFestivalDetail = routeLoader$(
  async (event: RequestEventLoader) => {
    const res = await performRequest<IGetSingleFestival>({
      query: GET_SINGLE_FESTIVAL,
      variables: { slug: event.params.slug },
    });
    return res.festival;
  },
);

export default component$(() => {
  const { value } = useGetFestivalDetail();

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{value.title}</h2>
      <p>{value.description}</p>
    </>
  );
});

export const onStaticGenerate: StaticGenerateHandler = async () => {
  const { allFestivals } = await performRequest<IGetAllFestivalSlugs>({
    query: GET_ALL_FESTIVAL_SLUGS,
  });

  return {
    params: allFestivals.map(({ slug }) => {
      return { slug };
    }),
  };
};

export const head: DocumentHead = ({ resolveValue }) => {
  const festival = resolveValue(useGetFestivalDetail);
  const meta = festival.seo
    .filter((tag) => tag.attributes !== null)
    .map(({ attributes }) => ({
      property: attributes?.property,
      content: attributes?.content,
    }));

  return { title: festival.title, meta };
};
```

I'm using DatoCMS as headless CMS through GraphQL.

One thing I've tried: I've tried to put all data inside the return inside `onStaticGenerate` but as far as I've understood I should just pass the path params, also I cannot put any values inside inside the `head` object.

`adapters/static/vite-config.ts`:

```
import { staticAdapter } from "@builder.io/qwik-city/adapters/static/vite";
import { extendConfig } from "@builder.io/qwik-city/vite";
import baseConfig from "../../vite.config";

export default extendConfig(baseConfig, () => {
  return {
    build: {
      ssr: true,
      rollupOptions: {
        input: ["@qwik-city-plan"],
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      staticAdapter({
        origin: "https://yoursite.qwik.dev",
      }),
    ],
  };
});
```

`vite.config.ts` inside my root project:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { qwikVite } from "@builder.io/qwik/optimizer";
import { qwikCity } from "@builder.io/qwik-city/vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    plugins: [qwikCity(), qwikVite(), tsconfigPaths()],
    dev: {
      headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=0",
      },
    },
    preview: {
      headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=600",
      },
    },
  };
});
```